# Testing RoutingMiddleware with CakePHP 3.7

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit

We have recently been trying to get Integration tests to work with our CakePHP 3.7 application. However we got a problem getting the routes to be found during the test.

Since the routing is added as Middleware we have the Application class load it in `Application::middleware()`. All our plugins are loaded in `Application::bootstrap()` and `Application::bootstrapCli()`.

When we dump the Router::routes() just before the $this->get or $this->post is called we see that all the routes are present, however once the $this->get is done we dump the response code with `$this->_request->getStatusCode()` we get a 404 and `$this->_getBodyAsString()` results in a HTML file with the message Error: Missing Route.

Reading the cookbook about [Integration testing](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#integration-testing) it seems you need to use the `$this->useHttpServer(true)` in the event of a custom Application class, however we use the standard App\Application

The only semi-working method we've found is by either using the routes.php found in the CakePHP skeleton application (because of the fallback) or circumventing the routes all together by using `$this->get(['controller' => 'class', 'action' => 'method'])`

However since we also want to test if the routes are working we would prefer to have the routing work properly.

We build our routes in routes.php by using `Router::scope` e.g

```
/**
 * testscope routes
 */
Router::scope(
    '/testscope',
    function (RouteBuilder $routeBuilder) {
        $controller = 'foobar';
        RouterHelper::buildApiRoutes(
            $routeBuilder,
            new Route('/foo', $controller, 'foo'),
            new Route('/bar', $controller, 'bar'),    
        );
    }
);
```

Which will create the routes /testscope/foo and /testscope/bar

The RouterHelper::buildApiRoutes contains the following code:

```
$apiHost = Configure::readOrFail('App.ApiHost');
foreach ($routes as $route) {
    $routeBuilder
        ->connect(
            $route->getPath(),
            ['controller' => $route->getController(), 'action' => $route->getAction()],
            self::buildOptionsForRoute($route)
        )
        ->setHost($apiHost);
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can make sure that the routes from config/routes.php are actually used?

Edit: Screenshot with the missing route error
[Missing route error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZTIq.png)

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always include the stacktrace (copied from the log files) in your questions! A screenshot of the error page in debug mode is also often very helpful, as it usually provides additional error info (copy the code from `_getBodyAsString()` into a `.html` file and open it in a browser). Also check what URL is being generated from the `['controller' => 'class', 'action' => 'method']` style URL array in the test environment, maybe it's not what you expect (for whatever reason).

Comment: I've just added a link to a screenshot with the missing route error. In the list with connected routes I've obfuscated our application specific route, but I've verified that the actual route I'm looking for is present with the correct controller and action parameters.

The stack trace on the left side is left unedited.

Comment: What I can see from that one route (from which I don't know whether it's actually a real route?), is that it has an empty string as action assigned (which can cause problems), and that it requires the host `hostname.local`. Do you actually configure the test request with the required host? And again, please check what the URL array actually generates in your test environment!

Comment: With the real data the action element of the array has the correct method within the controller. I've been too eager with blurring the application specific data, my apologies. The hostname.local is also a string I've put there in order hide our application data. The real headscratcher here is that eventhough the called route is present in the Connected routes list it still says that the route is missing.

Comment: What exactly the hostname is doesn't really matter, unless it's `localhost`, if it's something else, then what matters is whether you are configuring the test request to provide that host name (you'll get a missing route error when the host doesn't match), as in the PHP CLI environment, there is by default no host information (it defaults to `localhost`).